# Reading a html attribute as an array using Javascript / Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

Got a feeling this should be simple

I've got some html like this (I don't have control over the html)

```
<div class="something" data-spec="['thing','another-thing','one-more-thing']">Stuff</div>
```

I'm trying to read in the data-spec as an array without having to break it down into a string, splitting it up and then push the values into an array.

If I do this:

```
let elem = $('.something')
let attr = elem[0].attributes['data-spec']
console.log(attr)
```

It returns:

```
data-spec="['thing','another-thing','one-more-thing']"
```

Is there a way to read data-spec as an array object?

Thanks.

Comment: Change your output so that it's valid JSON?   (change the `'` to `"`) then JSON.parse.  Fix it at source rather than hack it at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing all single quotes with double quotes and then use `JSON.parse`

```
const dataSpec="['thing','another-thing','one-more-thing']"

JSON.parse(dataSpec.replace(/'/g, '"'))
```

```js
const dataSpec = "['thing','another-thing','one-more-thing']"
const array = JSON.parse(dataSpec.replace(/'/g, '"'))
console.log(array);
```

Comment: Nice one. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I'd otherwise say `JSON.parse()` it, but since those are single quotes, you can't directly do that.

The horrible option is `eval()`, but I think a happy middle ground (which could break if there are other quotes in the string) is

```
const attrString = elem[0].attributes['data-spec'];
// replace single quotes with double quotes for JSON parsing
const attr = JSON.parse(attrString.replace(/'/g, '"'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you can directly do what you want, but as a workaround you can use a regex to extract everything between quote, example :

```
var test = "data-spec=\"['thing','another-thing','one-more-thing']\"";
var result = test.match(/(?<=\').*(?=\')/);

console.log(result);
//will log : Array [ "thing','another-thing','one-more-thing" ]
```

Note: maybe you'll have to JSON.stringify(elem[0].attributes['data-spec']) to have the same string "test" that I have in my example

Answer (score 1):

Using *Vanilla* approach with `querySelector` to get the first matching element who has *class* `something`.

```js
const something = document.querySelector(".something");
const attr = something.dataset.spec; // You could also use something.getAttribute("data-spec")
console.log(attr); // "['thing','another-thing','one-more-thing']"
```

Get the values between quotes `"'"` using `match` with *flag* g to match all possible values between quotes.

```js
const elementsQuoted = attr.match(/'(.*?)'/g);//["'thing'", "'another-thing'", "'one-more-thing'"]
//Remove quotations by replacing any quote with empty string.
const array = elementsQuoted.map(element=>element.replaceAll("'",''));
```

***Result***

```
console.log(attr);//['thing', 'another-thing', 'one-more-thing']
```

> ***NOTE:*** You could split by regex pattern /','/ to get values of the array. but it needs to replace only open bracket in first element and closing bracket at last element.

```
attr.split(/','/g);//["['thing", 'another-thing', "one-more-thing']"]
```

##### [Never use eval!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#never_use_eval!)

As @AKX answer make a profit of `JSON` method `parse` by replacing single quotes with double quotes, since ***The JSON standard requires double quotes and will not accept single quotes.***